Decidability of CFL Equivalence with Fixed Regular Language
It is a well-known fact that the following problem is undecidable:

Instance: DFA $D$, CFG $G$ over the same alphabet $\Sigma$
Question: Is $L(D) = L(G)$?

This question is undecidable even when it is promised that $L(D) = \Sigma^\star$ when $|\Sigma| \ge 2$. However, this question is decidable given the promise that $L(D) = \emptyset$.
For each fixed regular language $R$ over a fixed alphabet $\Sigma$, does there always exist a proof of the decidability or undecidability of the following (modified) problem $P_R$?

Instance: CFG $G$ with alphabet $\Sigma$
Question: Is $L(G) = R$?

If so, is there a characterization on which regular languages $R$ has $P_R$ being decidable? (Of course, the answer is "yes" if we ask about Turing Machines instead of CFGs due to Rice's theorem.)
Based on comments, if $|\Sigma| = 1$ or the language of $R$ is finite, this modified question is decidable. Is it a necessary and sufficient condition for $R$'s language to be infinite and $|\Sigma| \ge 2$?

If $R$ generates a finite language $L(R) = {w_1,\dots,w_n}$ then $P_R$ is decidable, since it suffices to test that $w_1,\dots,w_n \in L(G)$ and that $L(G \cap \bar{R}) = \emptyset$.  I wonder if it is enough for $L(R)$ to be infinite for $P_R$ to be undecidable.

You also need at least two letters for undecidability

@Denis You mean that the case $|\Sigma| = 1$ is decidable, right?  (Since context-free = regular when $|\Sigma| = 1$, by Parikh's theorem.) But I don't see how to decide $L(G) = R$ even in the case that $|\Sigma| \ge 2$ but $R$ generates an infinite language of words over a single letter.

@NoamZeilberger I think the existence of a word generated by the grammar and containing some forbidden letter is decidable isn't it ? It looks like a variant of the emptiness problem. Then it boils down to the earlier case.

@Denis But how do you use the existence of such a word to decide language equality? You can decide $L(G) \subseteq L(R)$ for an arbitrary $R$ by testing $L(G \cap \bar R) = \emptyset$, but I don't see how you decide the inclusion $L(R) \subseteq L(G)$ even in the case that $L(R)$ is an infinite language contained in $a*$.

@NoamZeilberger What I meant is that if other letters than $a$ do not appear in $L(G)$ (decidable property), you can rewrite $G$ as a grammar on $\Sigma={a}$, and use Parikh's theorem to conclude on whether $L(G)=R$. But I haven't work out the details I might be missing some difficulty.

The question is asking to decide if $L(G) = R$ for an arbitrary CFG $G$. So I agree that it is decidable in the case that $\Sigma$ is a singleton which forces $G$ to generate a regular language, but otherwise I don't see how to decide it for arbitrary grammars in the $R$ infinite case.

@Denis I thought a bit more about this and now I see your point (sorry I missed it before).  I agree that the problem should be decidable in the case that $R$ is a language over a single letter $R \subseteq a^$, even if $\Sigma|$ contains more letters, because as you wrote it is possible to decide if $L(G) \cap (\Sigma \setminus a^) = \emptyset$, and then either reject (if $L(G)$ contains a word not in $a^*$) or else rewrite $G$ to an equivalent grammar over ${a}$ and reduce to the $|\Sigma| = 1$ case.

I also realized that there is a simple argument for undecidability in the case that $R$ is cofinite, by reduction from the undecidable problem $P_{\Sigma^}$. To decide if $L(G) = \Sigma^$, we would just check if $\bar{R} \subseteq L(G)$ (decidable since $\bar{R}$ finite), and then form the intersection grammar $G' = G \cap R$ and test $L(G') = R$.  So the $P_R$ problem is undecidable for $R$ cofinite (assuming $R$ contains more than one letter).  But I don't see how to prove undecidability in the case that $R$ is neither finite nor cofinite.

Intuitively we need to have the "space" to encode any TM run in the language $R$. For instance if the language $R$ is on alphabet ${a,b}$ but there is a bound on the number of $b$'s in words from $R$, I guess it will still be decidable, as it is "almost unary".

If on the contrary $R$ is "large" enough, for instance if for any $u$ there exists $v$ with $uv$ in $R$, (on an alphabet with at least two letters) then it is undecidable.

@Denis yes I agree on both counts.  For undecidability, I think it should be enough that $R$ contains a language of the form $u(x+y)^* v$, where $u,v \in \Sigma^*$ are arbitrary strings and $x\ne y \in \Sigma^n$ are two distinct strings of the same length $n > 0$.  This will be the case if the minimal automaton for $R$ has some state $q$ with two different cycles $q \to^n q$.

@NoamZeilberger I guess the following conjecture is natural then: The problem is undecidable if and only if $R$ has exponential growth. (it corresponds to your property, and is equivalent to just asking $x$ and $y$ to be non-commuting instead of same length)

And indeed the right-to-left direction (exponential growth => undecidability) seems ok, what could be trickier is to show that polynomial growth => decidability. Since polynomial growth regular languages are roughly a union of languages of the form $u_1^u_2^\dots u_k^*$, it might be possible to reduce to the unary case with some work.

that's a nice conjecture.  I didn't know this fact about polynomial growth regular languages so I'm recording a couple papers that seem relevant for reference (happy to hear if you have any others): "Characterizing regular languages with polynomial densities" (Szilard, Yu, Zhang, Shallit, 1992, https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-55808-X_48), "Finding the Growth Rate of a Regular of Context-Free Language in Polynomial Time" (Gawrychowski, Krieger, Rampersad, Shallit, 2008, https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-85780-8_27).

Fix an alphabet $\Sigma$.
A language $R$ is bounded if there exists words $w_1, w_2, \cdots, w_k$ such that $R \subseteq w_1^* w_2^* \cdots w_k^*$.
For a regular language $R$, the problem $P_R$ is decidable iff $R$ is bounded [1].
[1] J. E. Hopcroft: On the equivalence and containment problems for context-free languages, Mathematical Systems Theory 3 (1969), pp. 119–124, doi 10.1007/BF01746517.

Nice. This also confirms Denis' conjecture in the comments that $P_R$ is decidable iff $R$ has polynomial growth, since according to the article by Gawrychowski et al cited in the comments (and also referenced in this question), "a context-free language is bounded if and only if it has polynomial growth".

Oh, fun coincidence, I asked my question that you're linking to independently (without having seen your conversation with Denis in the comments). The motivation was that for word languages, there's a reduction from language growth to NFA ambiguity (which I'm interested in for other reasons) but it doesn't work over trees.
